# multiple readings from sqlite in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

Is there any problem with multiple Python threads (on same machine or from different machines connected on a network) reading from the same sqlite database, using Python's built in `sqlite` module? None of the threads write to the database, only read it. This [sqlite access from multiple threads for reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965041/sqlite-access-from-multiple-threads-for-reading) seems relevant but inconclusive. Is there a problem with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sqlite supports concurrent reading. See [the FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5). I imagine Python's sqlite module does the same. Just don't share cursors and connections between threads; create one for each.